# Why are the UV coordinates from dupli parent returning black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor, dupli-groups

I have a sphere UV mapped like so:

[image]

I parented a Suzanne to it and enable dupli verts, then setup a material on the Suzanne which I expected to color all the dupli Suzannes in a replica of the texture mapped to the sphere. Instead I just get all black:

[image]

However, generated coordinates work as expected:

[image]

Why do UV coordinates return all black?

[image]

Comment: I think that the node setup is correct, as it work as expected if you use a particle system instead of dupli verts. But it works ony with particles from faces (it make sense as texture belong to faces) but not with a grid distribution (and this make no sense...). Maybe there is a connection between this two issues.

Comment: @Carlo Ah, I think you found it. It works with duplifaces too, so it seems the answer is that it only works when the dupli objects are duplicated based on the parent's faces. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll write down something only because I'm assuming you are too busy. The bare truth is that I didn't think of that! But it sounds obiouvs now... Though I'm still wondering why it doesn't work with face grid particles...

Comment: Hm.. The grid distribution isn't *really* dependent on the arrangement of faces. I don't see why it couldn't work, but by the same token I don't see why it couldn't work with duplis instanced from vertices.. I guess these are just not implemented? Interestingly the tooltip for the BI version of this option says "Duplis instanced from verts, faces or particles, inherit texture coordinate from their parent"; despite not working on UVs for anything except faces.

Comment: I'm with you in saying it is not yet implemented. The subject is a little bit mysterious, I wasn't able to find any kind of documentation. And before today I was thinking that it would project the tex...while apparently it is just picking a color (maybe the one in the center?...) http://i.imgur.com/MSvaYIu.jpg

Comment: @Carlo Actually the reason I asked this question is because I'm attempting to [write some documentation](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/855/599) about it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because you are duplicating from verts.

Seems that Blender currently (2.75a) can't inherit coordinates of duplicated objects from the parent only if they are not duplicated from faces.

[image]

It would not be tehorically impossible to obtain the behavoiour you need as object mapping should not be strictly related to the way is generated, but for the moment it is.

---

The same issue is present with particles:

[image]

*Note: is not clear why it doesnt work with with grid option enabled...*